# Paper_trail gem: uninitialized constant VersionsController::Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I had this working fine following the Railscast episode by Ryan Bates and then some weeks later I went back to check on it and it was borked. Now I'm getting this error whenever I hit the undo button:

**uninitialized constant VersionsController::Version**

I have it set up exactly as in the screencast, but I have no clue what might have broken it.

Problem is on line 3 apparently:

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  def revert
    @version = Version.find(params[:id])
    @version.reify.save!
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Undid #{@version.event}"
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

Comment: Did you put a `has_paper_trail` in your model?

Comment: Hi here's the answer to my own question:

**The latest versions of Papertrail actually namespace the Version class as PaperTrail::Version**.


Fixed the problem immediately.

Comment: This was the second thing I would suggest you to do :). You should post your own answer and accept it for later visitors.

Comment: Can't my reputation is 1. Next time :)

Comment: Now maybe you can add your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest versions of Papertrail actually namespace the Version class as PaperTrail::Version. This will fix the problem immediately.

Here is an example:

```
def revert
  @version = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])
  if @version.reify
    @version.reify.save!
  else
    @version.item.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same problem, and unfortunately I don't understand what is meant by namespacing! Could you please post a sample code up to show what changes needs to be made? I'm sure it'll help other newbies like myself. Many thanks!

Comment: See the example I added above.